# Reloading a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView which holds Contacts (basically just a list of people). At the top of the UIViewController where that UITableView is, I have a button to add a new contact. When adding a new contact, a user presses a button "Done" to add that contact. I dismiss the view (which then makes the original view that has the UITableView in it show up) and attempt to reload the table to add the new contact. The new contact is added in the list of rows (an NSMutableArray), but it does not get refreshed when I call "reloadData" and the table won't update.

How and when can I update the UITableView to add the new contact?

Comment: Are you adding the contact to your mutable array before you make the call to -reloadData?  If you are reloading the table view before you add the contact to your array, then that is your problem.

Comment: I am adding it, and in fact, right before my "reloadData" call, I print it out to ensure it is added. But none of the table view methods are being called.

Comment: "But none of the table view methods are being called" so something is defintly wrong with your connexion. Do you use Interface Builder or do you code everything ? (I edited my answer a little bit too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you change `numberOfRowsInSection:` accordingly ?

You can avoid reloading entire table view by using:

```
insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked your all your outlets connexions in Interface Builder. You should have 'delegate' , 'datasource' and naturally your IBOutlet (corresponding to your UITableView )connected to your object. There are 3 connexions !